# Transfer files attached to notes on iPhone 5c to PC/macOS

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, notes.app, file-transfer

I want to transfer large ZIP files (up to 200 MB) attached to notes created with Notes app to my PC or macOS. Because I have a iPhone 5c running iOS 10, I can't install Google Drive, Dropbox, etc. When I long press the ZIP file and choose 'Share', I see 'Mail' and 'Whatsapp'. Since the files are so big, I can't email the files. Whatsapp no longer works because it isn't supported

Comment: There may be some mileage in backing up the phone to iTunes [or Finder in newer macOS] then poking inside the backup with something like [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) Ahhh… I can't test this, but I see it does include a utility to actually specifically export Notes.

Comment: Is there a free alternative to iExplorer?

Comment: Not that I've ever seen, no.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [Air Transfer app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/air-transfer-file-transfer-from-to-pc-thru-wifi/id521595136) to transfer the file from my device to my PC. When I shared the file from the Notes app, Air Transfer showed up, and I was able to put the file in the app. Air Transfer runs a webserver on the iPhone, and I opened up the provided link on my PC. The file showed on web page, and I was able to transfer the file to my PC. The transfer happened over my Wifi network.